# How to change compile settings for C/C++ VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to only compile(not run) a C/C++ code?
For me vscode always run the code when compiling the code. I want to just compile my code. Is it possible?
Executing the written code is working fine for me.

Would it be possible to only make the executable file? If so, how should I change the settings?
I currently use wsl ubuntu for vscode and gcc as a compiler.

Comment: Add a task to `tasks.json`.

Comment: don't use Code Runner but use tasks and launch configs, you can set a task as build task and use `Crtl+Shift+B`